# jQuery - Call a div class instead of a div id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still learning javascript and jQuery.

```
<script src="macy.js"></script>
<script>
    Macy.init({
    container: '#macy-container',
    trueOrder: false,
    waitForImages: false,
    margin: 24,
    columns: 2,
    breakAt: {
        1200: 5,
        940: 3,
        520: 2,
        400: 1
    }
    });
</script>
```

Instead of a div id called `macy-container`. I would like to call a class called `macy-container`.

This is what I tried:

```
<script src="macy.js"></script>
<script>
    Macy.init({
    container: '.macy-container',
    trueOrder: false,
    waitForImages: false,
    margin: 24,
    columns: 2,
    breakAt: {
        1200: 5,
        940: 3,
        520: 2,
        400: 1
    }
    });
</script>
```

It didn't work. I tried looking for a solution but other solutions didn't work.

Comment: Does the container have that class? The selector is correct for classes

Comment: Does an element with that class exist?

Comment: yes it does exist - '<div class="macy-container browse-selection-container">'

Comment: Well does Macy support a class? Impossible for us to tell.

Comment: Yes. Macy uses: var ele = function (selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
  }; So the problem is: is your code wrapped in document ready or window load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try wrapping the init in a document ready function. The page may not be done rendering and trying to find this class that hasn't been built yet.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    Macy.init({
    container: '.macy-container',
    trueOrder: false,
    waitForImages: false,
    margin: 24,
    columns: 2,
    breakAt: {
        1200: 5,
        940: 3,
        520: 2,
        400: 1
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @user6043723 If that is the case than the id version should have never worked...... Did it work in the first place.